# How can I use multiple return values from a regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, html, dom

I'm using regex to find links from a google calendar XML feed which show up in the form:

```
<a href="http://www.drsketchysdublin.com/event-registration/?ee=11">http://www.drsketchysdublin.com/event-registration/?ee=11</a>
```

and I want to replace this with

```
<a href="http://www.drsketchysdublin.com/event-registration/?ee=11">drsketchysdublin</a>
```

I'm using the following regex to match the text:

```
 expression = //(<a\shref="https?[^>]+>(https?:\/\/www\.([^\.]+)\.com[^<]+)<\/a>)/ig;
```

and then doing a replace using

```
return element.html( element.text().replace(expression, "<a href='$1' target='"+options.target+"'>$2</a>") );
```

where I want $1 to be the value of

```
(https?:\/\/www\.([^\.]+)\.com[^<]+)<\/a>)
```

and $2 to be the value of

```
([^\.]+)
```

I'm using code from here http://gabrielizaias.com/articles/jquery-urltolink-plugin/

How can I reference the two returned values from the regex? I've tried things like expression[0] but  with no luck.

Comment: First off, are you certain that your regex is matching correctly? (Also note many responses will criticize your use of Regex to navigate HTML, since that's a task JQuery's selectors are perfect for)

Comment: Pretty sure - I've been using [Rad Softare Regex Designer](http://rad-software-regular-expression-designer.software.informer.com/1.4/) to test it. 

As to your second point, you are probably correct but as I'll have to use regex at some point to extract the domain name I figured I might as well use it for the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function as the second argument to replace.  This function allows for arguments from the expression.  The arguments are (full match, [capturing items,] match offset, original string).  You can have multiple capturing items in this function.  A simple example:

```
var testItem = 'test1@test2';
var expression = new RegExp(/^([^@]+)@([^@]+)$/)
var returnItem = testItem.replace(expression, function(full_match, $1, $2, offset, original){
    console.log('full match: '+full_match)
    console.log('$1: '+$1)
    console.log('$2: '+$2)
    console.log('offet: '+offset)
    console.log('original: '+original)
    return (typeof $1 != "undefined" && typeof $2 != "undefined") ? $1+','+$2 : false; 
});
if (returnItem !== false) console.log(returnItem.split(','))
else console.log('bad return value');
```

The snippet declares a simple string, an expression that grabs the items on both sides of the @ sign, and then uses a replace function to return the two matched items after they have been parsed.  The console logs in the return function are there to demonstrate what each variable is holding.  After running the code above I received the following output:

```
full match: test1@test2
$1: test1
$2: test2
offet: 0
original: test1@test2
["test1", "test2"]
```

You can use this to parse the return from your regular expression with a small modification.
My sample code has an issue:  My return is using a split on a comma to create the array.  If your content could have a comma in it this will not work.

This isn't a problem for you, you can just use something like the following:

```
var temp = '<a href="http://www.drsketchysdublin.com/event-registration/?ee=11">http://www.drsketchysdublin.com/event-registration/?ee=11</a>'
var expression = /<a\shref="https?[^>]+>(https?:\/\/www\.([^\.]+)\.com[^<]+)<\/a>/ig;
var options = {target : 'blank'}

console.log(temp.replace(expression, function(full_match, $1, $2, offset, original){ return '<a href="'+$1+'" target="'+options.target+'">'+$2+'</a>';}))
```

just change the variables a bit (and change the console log into a return of course) and you should be fine.
Note that I removed a set of parenthesis from your regex, they didn't appear to be used for anything so I dropped them.  If you have any questions about making the regex more general let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for this extensive answer - it was just what I was looking for!